# Object doesn't support property or method 'toJSON' in IE7 - I have json2

Tags: jquery, json, internet-explorer-7

I keep getting the error:

Object doesn't support property or method 'toJSON'

I have json2 loaded. Works in all other browsers.

In head I have

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src ="js/libs/json2.js"></script>
```

Any suggestions on what might be causing this? I can't seem to find anything other than to include json2.js to fix the issue. Odd thing is I've had that for a while and this use to work.

Comment: The weird thing is it would appear that it is actually reading and working with the JSON, but I never use to get this error message. Makes me worried something might break.

Comment: This issue was some how related to the data-bind feature of Knockoutjs. I am using version 2.1 of Knockout and had a new template binding use `<div data-bind="template: { if: attribute_template() != false, name: 'attribute/'+attribute_template(), data: $data}"></div>` And in IE 7 and 8 it caused big problems with template binding. I had to just create an empty template to render if it is false vs using the visible binding. Someone when I fixed this my toJSON error went away... no idea why, but hopefully someone else finds this useful.

Answer (score 3):

json2 don't provide a `toJSON()` method.

Instead, you have to use `stringify` function

```
JSON.stringify( object );
```

You can see the full doc here: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js#L22

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear in that the problem is coming from a jquery $.getJSON() call.  However I think I may have gotten rid of the problem. Will post a comment on the main question about it for other.